# Selecting data from one table on the basis of another tables data one by one - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables

Table 1 - CommonTable

```
Id          Section
____________________
 1          Two-Wheeler
 2          Three-Wheeler
```

Table 2 - CategoryTbl

```
Id          Category                Section
___________________________________________________
 1          Two Wheeler             Two-Wheeler
 2          Three Wheeler           Three-Wheeler
 3          Four Wheeler           Four-Wheeler
 4          Other                   Others
```

Table 3 - ContentTbl

```
Id          CategoryId              Item
___________________________________________________
 1           1                       Bike
 2           1                       Scooter
 3           1                       Cycle
 4           2                       Car
 5           2                       Jeep
 6           4                       Truck
```

And the desired output is

```
Vehicle/Two-Wheeler/Bike
Vehicle/Two-Wheeler/Scooter
Vehicle/Two-Wheeler/Cycle
Vehicle/Three-Wheeler/Car
Vehicle/Three-Wheeler/Jeep
```

I tried to write following query

```
Select 'Vehicle/'+(select section from CommontTbl)+'/'+select item from 
 contenttbl where CategoryId=(select section from CommontTbl)
```

I know this query is wrong because `select section from commontbl` will return 
multiple values, so how can i fix this, using join or any thing please help me to find desired output

Comment: Try following answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
Select 'Vehicle/' + b.Category + '/' + a.Item from ContentTbl as a
left join CategoryTbl as b on a.CategoryId=b.ID
```

And if you want to Records from CommonTbl as base then try following,

```
Select 'Vehicle/' + b.Category + '/' + a.Item from ContentTbl as a
left join CategoryTbl as b on a.CategoryId=b.ID
inner join CommonTable as c on c.Section = b.Section
```

Comment: I think i have done enough work for today, it's simple but my mind was not working.. by the way Thanks........

Comment: It happens sometimes. But make sure it should happen only sometime, not every time. Try to be focused. All the best friend!